# How can I run / adapt a .sh file to windows environement

Tags: windows, cygwin, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following configuration file for a project.

It does not run on windows per se.
I have powershell installed, the linux subsystem, docker running, etc.

What steps should I follow to make the project run on windows ? I am a bit lost
Can I run it without cygwin ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

yell() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
die() { yell "$*"; exit 111; }
try() { "$@" || die "cannot $*"; }

# Path to your hosts file
hostsFile="/etc/hosts"

# Default IP address for host
ip="127.0.0.1"

hostnames="api.foodmeup.local"

removeHost() {
    if [ -n "$(grep -p "[[:space:]]$1" /etc/hosts)" ]; then
        echo "$1 found in $hostsFile. Removing now...";
        try sudo sed -ie "/[[:space:]]$1/d" "$hostsFile";
    else
        yell "$1 was not found in $hostsFile";
    fi
}

addHost() {
    if [ -n "$(grep -p "[[:space:]]$1" /etc/hosts)" ]; then
        yell "$1, already exists: $(grep $1 $hostsFile)";
    else
        echo "Adding $1 to $hostsFile...";
        try printf "%s\t%s\n" "$ip" "$1" | sudo tee -a "$hostsFile" > /dev/null;

        if [ -n "$(grep $1 /etc/hosts)" ]; then
            echo "$1 was added succesfully:";
            echo "$(grep $1 /etc/hosts)";
        else
            die "Failed to add $1";
        fi
    fi
}

addLinuxSSL() {
    sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foodmeup.local
    sudo cp ./.docker/nginx/ssl/foodmeup-ca.cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foodmeup.local
    sudo update-ca-certificates
}

addMacSSL() {
    sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ./.docker/nginx/ssl/foodmeup-ca.cert.pem
}

addCygwinSSL() {
    echo "Unable to add SSL for CygWin platform";
    exit;
}

while true; do
    echo "Do you wish to init the FoodMeUp API project?";
    read -p "(Y/N) " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* )
        echo "";

        echo -e "${BLUE}Setting local host names...${NC}";
        IFS=', '; array=($hostnames)
        for host in ${array[@]}; do addHost $host; done
        echo -e "${GREEN}Host names set!${NC}";
        echo "";
        echo "";

        echo -e "${BLUE}Prepping environment, please wait...${NC}";
        aws s3 cp s3://fmu-dev/ssl ./.docker/nginx/ssl/ --recursive --profile fmu

        unameOut="$(uname -s)"
        case "${unameOut}" in
            Linux*)     addLinuxSSL;;
            Darwin*)    addMacSSL;;
            CYGWIN*)    addCygwinSSL;;
            *)          exit;;
        esac

        rm ./.docker/nginx/ssl/foodmeup-ca.cert.pem

        aws s3 cp s3://fmu-dev/env-api-devel ./.env --profile fmu
        mkdir -p ./var/cache ./var/logs ./var/jwt ./var/cloud ./public/uploads
        aws s3 cp s3://fmu-dev/fmu-google-cloud.json ./var/cloud/FoodMeUp-dc2389a0a0cd.json --profile fmu
        JWT_PASSPHRASE=$(grep JWT_PASSPHRASE .env | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
        openssl genrsa -passout pass:${JWT_PASSPHRASE} -out ./var/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
        openssl rsa -passin pass:${JWT_PASSPHRASE} -pubout -in ./var/jwt/private.pem -out ./var/jwt/public.pem
        echo -e "${GREEN}Environment all set!${NC}";
        echo "";

        echo -e "${BLUE}Building Docker containers, please wait...${NC}";
        docker-compose up -d nginx;
        docker-compose up -d postgres;
        docker-compose up -d rabbitmq;
        echo -e "${GREEN}Docker containers built!${NC}";
        echo "";

        echo -e "${BLUE}Installing Composer dependencies, please wait...${NC}";
        docker exec -ti fmu_backend-php composer install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-suggest --optimize-autoloader;
        echo -e "${GREEN}Composer dependencies installed!!${NC}";
        echo "";

        echo -e "${BLUE}Generating assets, please wait...${NC}";
        docker exec -ti fmu_backend-php bin/console assets:install
        echo -e "${GREEN}Assets generated!${NC}";
        echo "";

        echo -e "${BLUE}Initializing application, please wait...${NC}";
        docker exec -ti fmu_backend-php /var/www/bin/phing init
        echo -e "${GREEN}Application initialized!${NC}";
        echo "";
        echo -e "${GREEN}[ALL DONE]${NC}";
        break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
echo -e "${GREEN}Project successfully installed${NC}";
```

Comment: check out https://batsh.org . Good luck.

Comment: I think you'll likely need to user Powershell for a *nix script that complicated and feature rich. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took each command one by one and tried to make it work

here is the result

```
function Green {
    process { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Green }
}

function Red {
    process { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red }
}


Write-output "Adding hosts...";
Set-HostsEntry -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -HostName 'api.foodmeup.local' -Description "FoodMeUp local API"
Write-output "Host added" | Green;

Write-output "Adding certificates...";
aws s3 cp s3://fmu-dev/ssl ./.docker/nginx/ssl/ --recursive --profile fmu
Import-Certificate -FilePath "./.docker/nginx/ssl/foodmeup-ca.cert.pem" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\Root

Remove-Item ./.docker/nginx/ssl/foodmeup-ca.cert.pem
aws s3 cp s3://fmu-dev/env-api-devel ./.env --profile fmu
'./var/cache','./var/logs','./var/jwt','./var/cloud','./public/uploads','./vendor' | % {New-Item -Name "$_" -ItemType 'Directory'}
aws s3 cp s3://fmu-dev/fmu-google-cloud.json ./var/cloud/FoodMeUp-dc2389a0a0cd.json --profile fmu

$file = ".env"
$pattern = "(?<=JWT_PASSPHRASE=).*"
$values=Select-String -Path $file -Pattern $pattern | 
    Select-Object -Expand matches | 
    Select-Object value
$JWT_PASSPHRASE=$values.value

openssl genrsa -passout pass:$JWT_PASSPHRASE -out ./var/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
openssl rsa -passin pass:$JWT_PASSPHRASE -pubout -in ./var/jwt/private.pem -out ./var/jwt/public.pem
Write-output "Certificates added successfully" | Green

Write-output "Granting rights on all folders...";
takeown /r /d y /f "var"
icacls "./var/" /grant:r Users:F /t
Write-output "Rights granted" | Green;

Write-output "Building and uping all containers..."
Write-output "Make sure to accept prompts asking to share project local drive or share it manually...";
docker-compose up -d
Write-output "All containers up!" | Green

Write-output "Installing dependencies, please wait..."
docker exec -ti fmu_backend-php php composer install
Write-output "Dependencies installed!" | Green

Write-output "Generating assets, please wait..."
docker exec -ti fmu_backend-php bin/console assets:install
Write-output "Assets generated!" | Green

Write-output "Initializing application, please wait..."
docker exec -ti fmu_backend-php /var/www/bin/phing init
Write-output "Application initialized!" | Green

Write-output "All done!" | Green
```